# Deleted point layer reappears upon refresh in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, enterprise-geodatabase, sql-server

I've deleted a point layer from a SQL Server geodatabase in ArcGIS Pro (using the Pro UI).   The deletion appears successful but upon refresh of the geodatabase, it reappears.

I haven't really seen any ESRI issues related to this, so I'm not really sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately I see this all the time, the only way I can fix is to close the project and re-open.  The edits should now display correctly, it appears to be a bug as far as I can tell.

Comment: This is what eventually happened.   None of the ESRI suggestions really worked and the layer just vanished one day.